# Moq Framework to unit test a method that returns a task

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I am new to this MOQ framework and honestly having a hard time with having to get my unit test to run. Basically, I have a C# application which basically does some uploads to APIs using PostAsync.

Now, since I can't (and should not) call the API during my unit test (as otherwise it would be an integration test), I added a wrapper method around it and allowing that method to return true by mocking it. But no matter what I do, it is returning false. I have gone through SO questions, but I am not sure what am I missing. I haven't used interfaces but am using classes with virtual methods.

Here is my sample code that I would want to test

```
public async Task<bool> CreateNoteBookDirectory (string url ,string bearertoken, JavaScriptSerializer jser,RestPostClass rest)
        {
            NoteBookDirectory jsnbdir = new NoteBookDirectory();
            jsnbdir.path = "/JobNotebooks/ClientScoreDataInput";

            var directorycreate = jser.Serialize(jsnbdir);
            var content = new StringContent(directorycreate, Encoding.UTF8, @"application/json");


            bool result=await rest.HttpPost(url, content, bearertoken);

            return result;
        }
```

This method is in the main class.

The RestPostClass class has the virtual method HttpPost, whose skeleton is somewhat like this

```
 public async virtual Task<bool> HttpPost(String url, StringContent content, string bearertoken)
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearertoken);
            // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(@"application/json"));
            var postresult = await client.PostAsync(url, content);
            bool result = parseResponse(postresult);
            return result;
        }
```

Now, in my unit test, I am trying to test the CreateNoteBookDirectory method and since do not want the post method to be called, mocking it.

Here is what I am doing in my sample unit test

```
 Mock<DataBricksRestPost> mock = new Mock<DataBricksRestPost>();
            mock.Setup(x => x.HttpPost("http://test.com", new StringContent("abc"), "token")).Returns(Task.FromResult(true));
            Program prog = new Program();
            var jser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            bool result= await prog.CreateNoteBookDirectory("http://test.com", "token", jser, mock.Object);
            Assert.IsTrue(result, "Test failed");
```

It keeps returning false because apparently the mocking does not really happen properly.

What am I missing?

Any questions and I will try my best to clarify.

P.S: I have used the existing the "program" class as I am basically starting.

Comment: What are you testing? http.Post or Notebook creation. You should only test business logic and not the external dependencies. Here the call to rest.HttpPost must be outside the CreateNoteBookDirectory(). Here SRP has been violated with Directory creation and HttpPost inside same method.

Comment: If you read the question , I have mentioned it clearly that I am testing CreateNoteBookDirectory and not HttpPost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mock returns *false*, because when you call `HttpPost` parameters don't match with ones that were set up. The second parameter is different.

You can set up mock like that:

```
mock
    .Setup(x => x.HttpPost("http://test.com", It.IsAny<StringContent>(), "token"))
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(true)); //or .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

It tells mocking framework, that second parameter can be any object of type `StringContent`.

Docs can be found here: https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#matching-arguments

Comment: Thanks for this. It indeed was the problem :). I wish I had seen it . Thanks again.